# How to read many images in java without memory leak

Tags: java, image, memory-leaks

I need to read many images to process them one after another. At first I used the IO library to read each image:

```java
File outputfile = new File(uri);
BufferedImage imgBuff = ImageIO.read(outputfile);
imgBuff.flush();
imgBuff = null;
outputfile = null;
```

However it takes up a lot of memory and my process crashes. After doing some research I found that there are many issues with reading many images using the java IO library. I used this simple progam to verify the memory leak was caused by reading the images using this image http://tinyurl.com/ku3ff7w:

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MemoryLeakTest {

  static File outputfile = null;
  static BufferedImage imgBuff = null;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String uri = "/home/user/Pictures/image.jpg";
    outputfile = new File(uri);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
      outputfile = new File(uri);
      try {
        imgBuff = ImageIO.read(outputfile);


      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (imgBuff != null) {
          imgBuff.flush();
          imgBuff = null;
        }
        outputfile = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried using the ImageJ library, but the same problem occured converting the image to BufferedImage:

```java
ImagePlus bb = op.openImage(uri);
imgBuff = bb.getBufferedImage();
bb.killStack();
bb.flush();
bb.close();
```

I guess I could read the images as byte arrays and that would solve the problem, but the solution is not ideal. Does anyone know if there is any library or method to read many images in Java without runing out of memory?

Comment: I modified your example to avoid code duplication, by introducing a `finally` block (which I think is better, but not really relevant in this case). Ran it with no problems. No memory leaks, from what I can see. I even tried to force it by using `-Xmx16m` command line option. Maybe you need a specific Java version, parameters or a special JPEG to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the image I'm using http://tinyurl.com/ku3ff7w. Maybe it's because that image is much larger.

Comment: @Victoria - I just ran the code with a 2mb image with no problems - however I had already increased my max heap space to 1GB, and by inserting some calls to `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` I could see the program using a fair chunk (~50%) of it. Have you profiled the memory use yourself? Try increasing your heap size (`-Xmx`) and maybe call `System.gc()` once every few iterations and see if that helps.

Comment: Even with your large image, I can run the example with `-Xmx16m`. No memory leaks there. I think you are either using a special Java version that might have a bug, or is simply confusing the terms "memory leak" and "high memory usage". Profiling is a good idea, to find out where the memory get stuck. Inserting `System.gc()` in your code is generally a bad idea, as Java will release any memory collectible by the garbage collector at some point. If you have a memory leak, the memory will not be collectible.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions was to use img4Java ( a java interface to ImageMagick commandline). 
In this way I delegate the image manipulation to an external process freeing JVM to go out fo memory.

see http://im4java.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.imagemagick.org/